# Proving $A\setminus(A\setminus B)=A\cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that for sets $A$ and $B$ we have $$A\setminus(A\setminus B)=A\cap B$$

I proceed as follows:

If $x\in A\setminus(A\setminus B),$ then $$\begin{align}x\in A \wedge x\notin(A\setminus B) \tag1& \iff x\in A \wedge (x\notin A \vee x\in B)\\ &\iff (x\in A \wedge x\notin A) \vee(x\in A \wedge x\in B)\tag2\\ & \iff x\in A \wedge x \in B\tag3\\ & \iff x\in A\cap B\tag4\end{align}$$

Thus since $A\setminus(A\setminus B)\subset A\cap B$ and $A\cap B \subset A\setminus(A\setminus B)$, we have

$$A\setminus(A\setminus B) = A \cap B$$

My question is: what does the $(x\in A \wedge x \notin A)$ contribute in line $2$? For the proof to work, one has to assume saying $x\in A \wedge x \notin A $ is equivalent to saying $x\in\emptyset$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement $x\in A\wedge x\notin A$ is indeed equivalent to the statement that $x\in\varnothing$.

But this purely on base of the fact that both statements are *false*.

It is for instance also equivalent to the statement that $1=2$.

Statement $p\vee q$ is a true statement iff $p$ is a true statement or $q$ is a true statement.

So if we observe in that situation that $p$ is false then we conclude that $q$ is true.

Comment: "But this purely on base of the fact that both statements are false." How do we know that a priori?

Comment: $\varnothing$ is by definition the unique set that satisfies $x\notin\varnothing$ for every $x$ or equivalently that $x\in\varnothing$ is false for every $x$. Further any statement of the form $p\wedge\neg p$ is false. If $q$ is a false statement then $q\to r$ is a true statement for every statement $r$. So if $q$ and $s$ are both false then they imply eachother hence are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. How could $x$ both be in $A$ and also not be in $A$? It never happens, so when we "or" that condition with anything else, we can equivalently just omit the impossible condition (which is how line 3 was obtained).

"I am seven years old and I am nine years old" or "I own a potted plant" is equivalent to "I own a potted plant".

Comment: Yep, that's also how I think about it. Thank you! I just wanted to be sure I am able to correctly describe the progression from line 2 to line 3.